# /usr/local/bin for OpenWrt

Tags: directory, path, openwrt

I’m attempting to add support for using Sublime Text and TextMate with files on the router: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RemoteSubl.

Essentially, the script needs to be added to the `/usr/local/bin`directory:

```
curl -o /usr/local/bin/rmate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aurora/rmate/master/rmate
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rmate
```

Unfortunately, the `/usr/local/bin` directory doesn’t exist (nor is it on the PATH):

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

Is there a recommended location for user-related scripts, such that they are on the PATH?

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be a problem to simply create the directory. (Keep in mind you will need to be root).

```sh
mkdir -p -m 755 /usr/local/bin
```

And to add that to `$PATH`, in `~/.profile`

```sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

---

Editor's notes:

- Tested on OpenWrt 18.06.4.
- Changed permissions to 755, which is the default on Ubuntu as per:

  ```
  $ stat -c '%a %A %n' /usr/local/bin /usr/local /usr
  755 drwxr-xr-x /usr/local/bin
  755 drwxr-xr-x /usr/local
  755 drwxr-xr-x /usr
  ```